# Outlook 365 1808 - Autodiscover with Postfix/Dovecot

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, outlook, autodiscover

The situation is :

- I have a mail server with Postfix, Dovecot and Apache2 for the autodiscover URL. Mail server is set up for TLS only (465, 993 and 995)
- the domain is controlled by myself (SRV record is setted up for autodiscover)
- Mail client is Outlook 365 with the lastest update (1808)

The first issue is when I try to add a new mail account, I'm not asking for the password and Outlook returns a error and I have to choose POP or IMAP account type.

Then, the second issue is coming. It found the `autodiscover.xml` file, but it only read the IMAP or the POP section, never the SMTP. And it always says : there are an error with SMTP server.

Here is my `autodiscover.xml` file :

```
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
 <Response xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a">
  <Account>
   <AccountType>email</AccountType>
   <Action>settings</Action>
   <Protocol>
    <Type>IMAP</Type>
    <TTL>1</TTL>
    <Server>imap.domain.tld</Server>
    <Port>993</Port>
    <DomainRequired>on</DomainRequired>
    <DomainName>domain.tld</DomainName>
    <SPA>off</SPA>
    <SSL>on</SSL>
    <AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
   </Protocol>
  </Account>
  <Account>
   <AccountType>email</AccountType>
   <Action>settings</Action>
   <Protocol>
    <Type>POP3</Type>
    <TTL>1</TTL>
    <Server>pop.domain.tld</Server>
    <Port>995</Port>
    <DomainRequired>on</DomainRequired>
    <DomainName>domain.tld</DomainName>
    <SPA>off</SPA>
    <SSL>on</SSL>
    <AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
   </Protocol>
  </Account>
  <Account>
   <AccountType>email</AccountType>
   <Action>settings</Action>
   <Protocol>
    <Type>SMTP</Type>
    <TTL>1</TTL>
    <Server>smtp.domain.tld</Server>
    <Port>465</Port>
    <DomainRequired>on</DomainRequired>
    <DomainName>domain.tld</DomainName>
    <SPA>off</SPA>
    <SSL>on</SSL>
    <AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
   </Protocol>
  </Account>
 </Response>
</Autodiscover>
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Use [Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/) to test Outlook Autodiscover and you may get some clues here.

Comment: I know this tool and i have already use it. No problem with it.... But my outlook find some

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem (just issue one) with Outlook365 and a pop3s autodiscover config.
it works with OL2016, but OL365 need the to choose the account type pop.

is there a way to set the account type automatically to pop3s ?